# Is this proof of open set right?

Tags: analysis

$\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{x}},\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)  $,
$_{[\mathsf{\mathbf{x}}=\left(  x_{1},\cdots,x_{n}\right)  \in R^{n}\text{
}\wedge\text{ }\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}=\left(  y_{1},\cdots,y_{m}\right)  \in
R^{m}]}$ $:=\left(  x_{1},\cdots,x_{n},y_{1},\cdots,y_{m}\right)  \in R^{n+m}$

$W:=\left\{  \mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\in R^{m}:\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{0}%
},\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)  \in V\subset R^{n+m}\right\}  $

$V$ is open in $R^{n+m}$, then $W$ is open in $R^{m}$

---

### proof :

---

### 1.

$V$ is open in $R^{n+m}$

$\rightarrow\forall\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{x}},\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)
\left(  \left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{x}},\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)  \in
V\rightarrow\exists r\left(  \left(  0<r\right)  \wedge\left(  N_{r}^{R^{n+m}%
}\left(  \left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{x}},\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)  \right)
=\left\{  \left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{x}}},\mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}\right)
\in R^{n+m}:\left\vert \left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{x}}},\mathsf{\mathbf{\hat
{y}}}\right)  -\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{x}},\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)
\right\vert <r\right\}  \subset V\right)  \right)  \right)  $

---

### 2.

$\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\in W$

$\rightarrow\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{0}},\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)  \in V$

since 1.

$\rightarrow\exists r\left(  0<r\wedge N_{r}^{R^{n+m}}\left(
\mathsf{\mathbf{0}},\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)  =\left\{  \left(
\mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{x}}},\mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}\right)  \in R^{n+m}%
:\left\vert \left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{x}}},\mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}}%
}\right)  -\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{0}},\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)  \right\vert
<r\right\}  \subset V\right)  $

---

### 3.

$\mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}\in N_{r}^{R^{m}}\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{y}%
}\right)  =\left\{  \mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}\in R^{m}:\left\vert
\mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}-y}}\right\vert <r\right\}  $

$\rightarrow\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}\in R^{m}\right)  \wedge\left(
\left\vert \mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}-y}}\right\vert <r\right)  $

since : $\left\vert \mathsf{\mathbf{x}}\right\vert ,_{\left[
\mathsf{\mathbf{x}}\in R^{k}\wedge\mathsf{\mathbf{x}}=\left(  x_{1}%
,\cdots,x_{k}\right)  \right]  }:=\left(  {\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}x{_{{{i}}}%
^{2}}}\right)  ^{1/2}$

$\rightarrow\left(  \left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{0}},\mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}}%
}\right)  \in R^{n+m}\right)  \wedge\left(  r>\left\vert \mathsf{\mathbf{\hat
{y}-y}}\right\vert =\left\vert \left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{0-0}}%
,\mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}-\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)  \right\vert =\left\vert
\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{0}},\mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}\right)  -\left(
\mathsf{\mathbf{0}},\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)  \right\vert \right)  $

since 2. $N_{r}^{R^{n+m}}\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{0}},\mathsf{\mathbf{y}%
}\right)  =\left\{  \left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{x}}},\mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}%
}}\right)  \in R^{n+m}:\left\vert \left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{x}}%
},\mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}\right)  -\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{0}}%
,\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)  \right\vert <r\right\}  $

$\rightarrow\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{0}},\mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}\right)  \in
V$

$\rightarrow\mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}\in W$

---

### 4.

by 3.

$\rightarrow\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}}}\in N_{r}^{R^{m}}\left(
\mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)  \right)  $....$\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{\hat{y}}%
}\in N_{r}^{R^{m}}\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)  \right)  $

$\rightarrow N_{r}^{R^{m}}\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\right)  \subset W$

---

### 5.

by 2. 3. 4.

$\rightarrow\exists r\left(  0<r\wedge N_{r}^{R^{m}}\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{y}%
}\right)  \subset W\right)  $....$\left(  \mathsf{\mathbf{y}}\in W\right)  $

$\rightarrow W$ is open in $R^{m}$

Comment: I can't follow this. I suggest foregoing many of the symbols and use more words to fill in the details.

Comment: I agree with Sean. I think you should change you first step in something like $\forall(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y})\in V$, $\exists \ r>0$ s.t. the ball of radius $r$ and center  $(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y})$ is contained in $V$, i.e.   $N_{r}^{R^{n+m}}((\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y}))
=\{(\boldsymbol{x}',\boldsymbol{y}')\in R^{n+m}:\vert (\boldsymbol{x}',\boldsymbol{y}')  -(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y})\vert <r\}  \subseteq V$

Comment: ...and do the same with the other steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and no.

The proof looks formally correct, **but** still it looks a lot like smoke-and-mirror. Basically anyone that is able to actually follow the proof would probably find the statement quite obvious - which would make the proof so much easier.

Instead you should have written it in a way that makes it easier to follow. I don't think it even gets more compact by using a lot of "symbol-language", so that won't do as an excuse:

Basically you start with $y\in W$ and from definition you have $(0,y)\in V$ which means that since $V$ is open you have an $r>0$ such that whenever $|(u,v)-(0,y)|<r$ you have $(u,v)\in V$. Especially we have that whenever |$(0,v)-(0,y)|<r$ we have $(0,v)\in V$ and therefore $v\in W$.

That is for every $y$ in $W$ we have an $r>0$ such that whenever $|u-y|<r$ we have $u\in W$, which means that $W$ is open.

Perhaps it's by omitting the constructs where open sets are defined in terms of neighborhoods being a subset of the set is one thing that simplifies the proof. Anyway even by including the proof that the two definitions of openness is equivalent I'd say it would make the proof more compact **and** more easy to follow that yours.